# How to open all any fomat files on Android

Tags: android, android-intent

I try to implement a browser-like app.
I want to let it can open any format files which supported by device.
I know below code can open specific format:

```
String mimetype = mime_type(FileName);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(File), mimetype);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);

public String mime_type(String name) {
String type = null;
String[] mime = {".htm\ttext/html", ".html\ttext/html", ".doc\tapplication/msword", ".ppt\tapplication/vnd.ms-powerpoint", ".xls\tapplication/vnd.ms-excel", 
                ".txt\ttext/plain", ".pdf\tapplication/pdf", ".xlsx\tapplication/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", 
                ".pptx\tapplication/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation", ".docx\tapplication/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"};
int i;
for(i = 0; i < mime.length; i++) {
if(name.toLowerCase().endsWith(mime[i].split("\t")[0])) {
return mime[i].split("\t")[1];
}
}
return type;
}
```

But the file formats are more than I can list.
If any methods to do it for all formats?
Or any methods to list all applications let user select?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find set mimetype to `*/*` can arrive it.
It will show all intalled app for select.